# Defragmenting indexes SQL Server bases on avg_page_space_used_in_percent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, maintenance, performance-tuning

I am wondering if I should take into account information from

```
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
```

column

```
avg_page_space_used_in_percent
```

when deciding on defragmenting/not defragmenting an index.

How is it possible that I see low `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` value and also low value for `avg_page_space_used_in_percent`?

Based on Brent Ozar [article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) I could think that I should rebuild an index as there is a lot of free space on pages so it is a waste of disk and RAM space.
But scripts as [Ola Hallengren's](https://ola.hallengren.com/), for example, analyze only `avg_fragmentation_in_percent`, don't they?

Comment: What is the size of the table in question?

Comment: Consider a freshly rebuilt index with a low fill factor will have both low fragmentation and avg space used.

Comment: While `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` shows level of fragmentation which means *out of order* pages ,`avg_page_space_used_in_percent` indicates page fullness. They are not directly related and the latter has little significance in fragmentation.  Yes if the value is high means there might have been lot of page splits and this have created lot of space on page.

Comment: @gbn, 5468 pages

Comment: @Shanky so page splits not necessarily lead to fragmentation? They can lead only to page fullness? Does not seen correct.... the point of the question however was 'should I rebuild indexes based on avg_page_space_used_in_percent?'

Comment: Unless you want every possible iota of speed for a process, or every possible byte of free space, I wouldn't rebuild based on the page space used. Low page space used means that more out-of-order inserts can be placed into the index without causing fragmentation issues. Although a rebuild means that you will have fewer total pages (unless of course your fill factor is fairly low), it also means that additional inserts will generate more page splits.  **tl;dr** you flip the coin and you take your chances.

Comment: @GeorgeK The page splits do cause fragmentation and they are mostly a physical one while the index fragmentation which we are talking is logical one where the ordering of pages do not match that of clustering key. Both are equally bad. Rebuilding will only fix logical fragmentation unless you use fill factor which will make sure how much free space is left and would take care of page splits. Now you should still consider the column `avg_fragmentation_in_percentage`

Answer (score 1):

I have these rules of thumb:

- if there are fewer than 10,000 pages in a table, I don't really care about fragmentation;
- if the storage layer is solid-state, I don't really care about fragmentation;
- once or twice a month I might rebuild indexes on really fragmented tables, but only if fragmentation is demonstrably causing performance issues, which it usually isn't.

Fill factor can affect fragmentation, as can page splits, bad clustered index choices, and so on. Find the actual performance issues using a baseline, and focus on those.